# Multiple attributes in ng-style in angular2

Tags: angular

I have the following property to implement flexbox on an element:

```
flex : ['-webkit-box','-moz-box', '-ms-flexbox','-webkit-flex', 'flex']
```

The template looks as follows :

```
<home [style.display]="flex"></home>
```

But its not working. How can I implement the full arrow on the [style.display] property without using [ng-style].

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use a class for this? Or better, there is [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) that can add prefixes to your CSS files as necessary.

**CSS:**

```
.flex {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   /* ... */
   display: flex;
}
```

Or is a general question?